# Same code different Table name gives Error! in Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, nosql

working with apache Cassandra in Jupyter Notebook, creating a table, and inserting data all works fine. after I change the Table name, respectively, gives an error!

**the working first code:**

```
session.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 
(artist text , song text, firstname text , lastname text, userId int ,sessionid int, iteminsession int , 
PRIMARY KEY ((userId, sessionId), itemInSession)) """)


file = 'event_datafile_new.csv'    

with open(file, encoding = 'utf8') as f:
   csvreader = csv.reader(f)
   next(csvreader) # skip header
   for line in csvreader:
       
       query = "INSERT INTO table2 (artist, song, firstname, lastname , userId, sessionId, itemInSession)"
       query = query + "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s ,%s ,%s ,%s)"
       
   
       # building the insert
       # executing the insertion
       session.execute(query , (line[0], line[9], line[1], line[4], int(line[10]), int(line[8]), int(line[3])) )
         



query = "select artist, song, firstname, lastname from table2 WHERE userId= 10 and sessionId = 182"

try:
   rows = session.execute(query)
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
   
for row in rows:
      print(f'artist: {row.artist}, song: {row.song}, user first name: {row.firstname},user last name: {row.lastname}')
```

**changing  table name from 'table2' to 'artist_song' getting error: InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined column name firstname"**

```
session.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artist_song
(artist text , song text, firstname text , lastname text, userId int ,sessionid int, iteminsession int , 
PRIMARY KEY ((userId, sessionId), itemInSession)) """)


file = 'event_datafile_new.csv'    

with open(file, encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    next(csvreader) # skip header
    for line in csvreader:
        
        query = "INSERT INTO artist_song (artist, song, firstname, lastname , userId, sessionId, itemInSession)"
        query = query + "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s ,%s ,%s ,%s)"
        
    
        # building the insert
        # executing the insertion
        session.execute(query , (line[0], line[9], line[1], line[4], int(line[10]), int(line[8]), int(line[3])) )
          


query = "select artist, song, firstname, lastname from artist_song WHERE userId= 10 and sessionId = 182"

try:
    rows = session.execute(query)
except Exception as e:
    print(e) 
for row in rows:
       print(f'artist: {row.artist}, song: {row.song}, user first name: {row.firstname},user last name: {row.lastname}')
```

Comment: Perhaps the table already existed, and it doesn't have such a column?

Comment: it's a new table, tried also to DROP TABLE in case yet same issue!

Comment: Are you sure `firstname` isn't defined as `first_name` somewhere in there?  Couldn't help but notice a mix of lowercase, camel case and snake case in the table definition.  That's a recipe for confusion.